# python code to convert input data into json format variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a input variable(stud_id), list(sub_code) and array(data) with the below values.

```
stud_id: 10

sub_code: ['002', '003', '007']

data: [array([['867192', '5545']], dtype=object), array([['964433', '0430']], dtype=object), array([['965686', '2099']], dtype=object)]
```

How to convert the above input into json format like this?
stud_id is the main key

```
output =       '{ "10" : { "002" : [ 867192, 5545 ], '\
               '           "003" : [ 964433, 0430  ], '\
               '           "007" : [ 965686, 2099 ] } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to adjust your array type for testing.

Try this code:

```
stud_id = 10

sub_code = ['002', '003', '007']

#data = [array([['867192', '5545']], dtype=object), 
#        array([['964433', '0430']], dtype=object), 
#        array([['965686', '2099']], dtype=object)]

data = [['867192', '5545'], 
        ['964433', '0430'], 
        ['965686', '2099']]


output =       '{ "10" : { "002" : [ 867192, 5545 ], '\
               '           "003" : [ 964433, 0430  ], '\
               '           "007" : [ 965686, 2099 ] } }'
               
dd = {str(stud_id):{k:a for k,a in zip(sub_code, data)}}

print(dd)
```

Output

```
{'10': {'002': ['867192', '5545'], '003': ['964433', '0430'], '007': ['965686', '2099']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import json
>>> from numpy import array
>>> stud_id = 10
>>> sub_code = ['002', '003', '007']
>>> data = [array([['867192', '5545']], dtype=object),
...         array([['964433', '0430']], dtype=object),
...         array([['965686', '2099']], dtype=object)]
>>> json.dumps({stud_id: dict(zip(sub_code, map(lambda arr: arr[0].tolist(), data)))})
'{"10": {"002": ["867192", "5545"], "003": ["964433", "0430"], "007": ["965686", "2099"]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip `sub_code` and `data`, turn them into a dict with a dict comprehension, then put them in another dictionary with `stud_id` as a key, then dump as json:

```py
import json

json.dumps({stud_id: {k: v.tolist()[0] for (k, v) in zip(sub_code, data)}})
# '{"10": {"002": ["867192", "5545"], "003": ["964433", "0430"], "007": ["965686", "2099"]}}'
```